# scala append to to list of tuples in foldLeft?

Tags: scala

I'm a beginner in scala, and I'm wondering how to append, or create a new list of tuples with a tuple at the head of another tuple.

Right now I am doing

```
list.foldLeft(List[(String, Int)]())((ll:List[(String, Int)], str:String) => 
if (str == ll.head._1) (str, ll.head._2 + 1) :: ll.tail.head
else (str, 1) :: ll.head)
```

However the error I get is that there is no :: operator for tuples.

Comment: Can you give an example for expected result? What do you mean appending a tuple at the head of another?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, the reason for this is that you're trying to use the first element of the tail of the list rather than the tail itself as the right-hand argument to `::`.

You should be able to use something like:

```
list.foldLeft(List[(String, Int)]())((ll, str) =>
  if (str == ll.head._1) (str, ll.head._2 + 1) :: ll.tail
  else (str, 1) :: ll)
```

However you'll then hit an error from trying to take the head of an empty list. So a full working version would be like

```
list.foldLeft(List[(String, Int)]()) {
  case ((hs, hc) :: tail, str) if hs == str ⇒ (str, hc + 1) :: tail
  case (ll, str) ⇒ (str, 1) :: ll
}
```